# Storing routes on the PHP file (default) or on a database in Symfony and Laravel?

Tags: laravel, symfony, routes

Can you explain to me why in Back-End frameworks like Symfony, Laravel, ASP.NET Core MVC, etc. storing routes on file (default) is preferred on a database? (by creating new middleware)

I have many years of experience in analyzing systems, designing databases, and developing web applications also implementing some custom frameworks with the approach of storing routes on a database however, I don't have any ideas about storing routes on a file and its benefits.

On the other hand, I think storing routes on a database has many advantages such as less Ram capacity, more speed for finding a route, flexibility in managing routes and authorization with web forms by ordinary admin users, and so on.

Someone can convince me storing web application routes on a file is better than on a database?

I created a middleware that gets route name and search and select route data (permission type, relevant controller, etc.)  from a database. This way is great for full control managing routes using some web form for ordinary Admin users that can create new routes, delete or edit them, and change permissions. instead of directly coding by developers on the default route file.

However, I can't understand why routes are placed on a huge file and this way has what advantages?

Maybe I have made a mistake all of the past years in storing routes on a database.

Comment: How would an Admin creating Routes via a Web Form work in Laravel? Routes are connected to functions or Controller actions, which need to be coded by a Developer for them to do anything... You _could_ store Laravel's Routes in a Database table, and construct the routes dynamically from Objects from your database, like `Route::{$route->verb}($route->path, [$route->controller, $route->method])->name($route->name)`, but that relies on the Controller and Method existing, otherwise your app will throw errors. You'd still need a Developer to hook up the Routes the Admin would create via your form...

Comment: Stackoverflow is probably not the best place for these sorts of things.  In Symfony, routes are typically defined as attributes on your controllers.  Same sort of thing that many C# frameworks do.  Symfony has a compile (aka build) phase which collects all these routes and caches them.  Not really a great big file of routes.  But Symfony does allow dynamic routes which can be pulled from a database.  Your choice.  Like @TimLewis I don't really know what would happen after the administrator defines a new route.